# Oxidative cleavage of alkenes by Chromic Oxide

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

Does CrO3 (hot concentrated or acidified like Jones Reagent) cleave alkenes and alkynes like hot conc KMnO4 would, like this reaction?
[image]
If not, why not? And do any other reagents other than Ozone capable of oxidative cleavage of $\pi$ bonds?

Comment: Osmium Tetroxide + Sodium Periodate will cleave alkenes to dicarbonyls - search Johnson Lemieux oxidation.

Comment: thanks! but what about the chromic oxide?

Comment: Chromic oxide does not typically cleave alkenes